# Making a categorical variable from a continuous datetime variable

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, categorical-data

I am trying to make a categorical variable from a continuous datetime variable.

Basically if they are between 15 and 25, then Age_category = 1, if they are between 25 and 35, then Age_category = 2.

I've got it so that I can make one condition, this works:

```
df.loc[(df['Age_days'] > timedelta(days=(25*365)), 'Age2')] = '1'
```

When I try and make two conditions it fails:

```
df.loc[(df['Age_days'] > timedelta(days=(15*365)) & (df['Age_days'] <= timedelta(days=(25*365)), 'Age_cat'))] = '1'
```

The error I get says that it doesn't like the use of '&':

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'tuple'
```

I've tried replacing & with 'and' but it also doesn't like that:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any idea how I should fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Pandas, you should use Pandas methods rather than the `datetime` module.

In this instance, you can NumPy to convert `timedelta` values to `float`, and then use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) to bin your ages. By default, `pd.cut` is inclusive on the right of each range.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [10, 15, 17, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]})
df['Age'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Age'], unit='Y')

df['Category'] = pd.cut(df['Age'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y'), [15, 25, 35], labels=[1, 2])

print(df)

                  Age Category
0  3652 days 10:12:00      NaN
1  5478 days 15:18:00      NaN
2  6209 days 02:56:24      1.0
3  7304 days 20:24:00      1.0
4  9131 days 01:30:00      1.0
5 10957 days 06:36:00      2.0
6 12783 days 11:42:00      2.0
7 14609 days 16:48:00      NaN
```

You can then drop null values and convert categories to `int` (if required).